# Вывод содержимого новости в другом ресурсе

Tags: modx

Прошу совета.
Как в MODX правильно реализовать вывод содержимого страницы "галерея" (id2) (дочерние ресурсы другого ресурса) на главной странице (id1)?
Пробовал через сниппеты `pdoResources` и `getResources`, выводит 3 элемента, всё как нужно (3 имеющиеся новости), но не отображаются картинки подгружаемые через TV поле MIGX (не прописывается путь). Префиксы tv. для полей, тоже указывал сейчас `[[tv.image]]`
Вот мой пример вывода:

```
       [[!getResources?
            &parents=`2`
            &depth=`0`
            &limit=`0`
            &includeTVs=`gallery`
            &tpl=`gallery-item-tpl`
        ]]
```

Comment: тв поля вызываются [[+tv.image]] (если в шаблоне [[*tv.image]]) ну и проверьте соответствие имен в вызове сниппета, должно быть: &includeTVs= `image`

Comment: [[+tv.image]] вызов у меня прописан именно так и  [[+tv.title]] для названия.
И пробовал прописывать &includeTVs=`image, title`, тоже не работает

Comment: пропустил, что выводите migx, у вас есть необходимость в нем? т.е. в одной новости может содержаться несколько картинок и описаний (несколько записей в тв поле migx) и как называется ваше тв поле migx?

Comment: Да, есть необходимость - 5 картинок, прайс и заголовок, мне кажется я пытаюсь сделать то, что не поддерживается в modx.
Мне нужно на главной странице, выводить содержимое страницы "галерея"  - слайдером, т.е. должен быть слайдер, а слайды показывают tv поле каждого дочернего ресурса страницы "галерея" на главной странице.
Возможно ли такое?
И как я понял, получается на страничке с галереей (id2) вызов &parents=`2`  pdoResources прекрасно работает, а вот на главной (id1) вызов &parents=`2` не работает

Comment: Сделать можно, дополните вопрос кодом migx, или напишите его название, и названия полей в нем